# Why is the output voltage of an electric generator limited to 25 kV?

Tags: electric-machine, physical-design

I'm currently studying electrical machines, and reading the book I found the following statement:

> The output voltage of an electric generator is usually limited to 25 kV due to physical considerations.

My teacher also emphasized that statement during class, but neither the teacher nor the book gave more information about it.

Could someone give me more information or explain these considerations?

Comment: My counter question is, have you thought what it might require to build a generator with higher voltage, pick any, like 100 or 1000 kilovolts?

Comment: This means nobody builds ones with higher voltage. It means either they're really hard or just annoying to build. Probably because of the amount of space between the conductors to stop them from arcing.

Comment: You need to keep mechanical clearances (gaps) small to make the magnetic circuit efficient. This constrains the insulation breakdown voltage as @user253751 suggests.

Comment: Check into the insulation break down as the distance between phases is close.

Answer (score 0):

This remembers me of the same voltage limit for old color TV anode voltages. This was typically 25 kV, absolute maximum was 27.5 kV. The reason was, that at 30 kV the tube begins to emit significant X-ray radiation via
[Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung). Maybe the fear from this invisible danger handed down this limit over the decades.